# PHP - regex to allow numbers and symbols only

Tags: php, regex

Hi i am tying to get clean date but there is some thing wrong.

Here is my code.

```
$in = 'Kb   06/11/2001';

$result = preg_replace("/[^0-9]+/", "", $in);

echo $result;
```

Output is

```
06112001
```

i need output `06/11/2001`

Comment: Like preg_replace("/[^0-9\/]+/", "", $in)?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Match the slash as well to get the clean date `/[^0-9\/]+/`

```
$result = preg_replace("/[^0-9\/]+/", "", $in);
```

Answer (score 1):

You could also make use of simple array functions in PHP. `[A regex alternative`]

```
<?php
$in = 'Kb   06/11/2001';
echo $arr= array_pop(explode(' ',$in));  //"prints" 06/11/2001
```

[Demo](https://eval.in/105053)

The code explodes your text by space and then pops your last element which is your date.